# Problem with testing cli prompts interactively, scanner is not waiting for user input

Tags: unit-testing, go

I try to write a test to verify cli prompts, emulate user inputs in response to some program outputs.

How to make `scanner.Scan` wait for the rest of the writes?

What I have so far:

```golang
    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    fmt.Fprint(b, "0")
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
            fmt.Fprint(b, i)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(b)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Print(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("problem while scanning:", err)
    }
```

Expected result is: `0123`

Actual result is: `0`

I tried a version with io.Pipe

```
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    fmt.Fprint(w, "0")
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
            fmt.Fprint(w, i)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Print(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("problem while scanning:", err)
    }
```

result: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Comment: Use an [io.Pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Pipe) instead of a buffer.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I modified the example to use io.Pipe, but it seems that the scanner never reads it now. I'm getting `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error.
But maybe I'm not using io.Pipe correctly. I added the modified version to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a pipe, writes and reads are synchronous. A Write cannot complete without a matching Read. Move the first write into the goroutine. And Close the writing end of the pipe to allow the scanner to stop scanning.

```golang
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        defer w.Close()

        fmt.Fprint(w, "0")

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
            fmt.Fprint(w, i)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Print(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("problem while scanning:", err)
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks, that works like I expected. Just out of curiosity, do you know why it doesn't work with bytes.Buffer?

Comment: Because if you call Scan when the buffer is empty it returns (0, io.EOF), signaling that no more data is to be read.